# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weasyprint'

Tags: django, weasyprint

I have installed `WeasyPrint==0.42.3` using `pip3 install WeasyPrint==0.42.3`, but when I try to import it in Django, it raises the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weasyprint'
```

When I look at the `requirements.txt`, it actually shows that it is installed.

I am using Django==2.1.5, python==3.8.5. another issue I am encountering is, the version of Django I am using is not listed in the requirements.txt, but when I check the version from the terminal, it shows that I am using the above named version.

Comment: How *exactly* did you install it?

Comment: I used; pip3 install WeasyPrint==0.42.3

Comment: It's possible that you've installed the package into different python installation. Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: I was able to collect it by adding the path to its location using; export 'PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages' . Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score -2):

```
pip install django-weasyprint
```

this worked for me